# Могу ли я пользоваться Microsoft Visual Studio( бесплатная версия) в коммерческих целях?

Tags: visual-studio

Какую версию лучше приобрести для использования в коммерческих целях?

Comment: кем будет использоваться? Лично тобой, либо организацией?

Comment: [_Любой индивидуальный разработчик может создавать бесплатные или платные приложения с помощью Visual Studio Community._](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/community/)

Comment: @Grundy, лично мной

Comment: Выдержка из [лицензионного соглашения](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt553321/): _**Individual License.** If you are an individual working on your own applications to sell or for any other purpose, you may use the software to develop and test those applications._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [официальной странице](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/compare/) сравнения версий Visual Studio, Community Edition можно использовать:

- Если Вы индивидуальный разработчик
- Для обучение в аудиториях
- Для научного исследования
- Для участия в проектах с открытым кодом
- Если Вы не корпоративная организация (т.е. организация с не более чем 250 ПК или годовым доходом не свыше 1 млн долларов США) и до 5 пользователей

Если Вы не попадаете под указанные критерии, то необходимо версия выше, а какая конкретно зависит от Ваших требований.
Для небольших организаций имеет смысл использовать [Microsoft Action Pack](https://partner.microsoft.com/ru-kz/membership/action-pack).

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, то у Visual Studio есть три варианта:

1. Community - это бесплатная версия где вы можете разрабатывать что угодно, она бесплатна для образовательных организаций и проектов с открытым исходным кодом. Проще говоря если у вас школа или универ, то вы можете ее брать. Или же если у вас проект который будет в открытом доступе находится.
2. Professional - это уже посерьезнее чем community, поскольку тут доступно больше надстроек но насколько я знаю эту версию уже нужно покупать. И она вообще предназначена для одного пользователя и в компании если ее выбирать то будет дороговато.
3. Enterprise - это то что вам нужно. Версия для использования в организациях. Вы приобретаете ключ на определенное кол-во машин и можете ее использовать в коммерческих целях.

Я возможно где-то допустил ошибку, если кто-то заметил неточность в описании прошу написать в комментариях или отредактировать вопрос так как я писал чисто мое мнение основанное на моем опыте.

Comment: То есть для фриланса и бесплатная подойдет?

Comment: вполне, либо крякнутую можете где-то найти, но это лишняя морока)